# Wordpress options table row quantity keeps changing on refresh?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying out a new wordpress site theme in my test server from an original wordpress site I copied from a different server and database. I didn't want the development version to tap into the original DB so I copied the WP DB to my test server. In the process I noticed that the options table in the development version has a cardinality that keeps changing.

If I am correct, that represents the number of rows in the table right?

If the original DB table I exported from has a cardinality of 258, why would that change in the development version where I copied the same table to? If that represents the number of rows (If I am right on this) then why are they changing every time I refresh? Shouldn't the value be the same every time? 258?

In the original version, when I refresh the value always stays the same.

Any insight on this would be very helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

WordPress instances put all kinds of data, including temporary data, into `wp_options`. Plugins, themes, and the core all use that table. There is probably nothing amiss here.

You will need to do some more breakdown of the rows in that table if you really think something is wrng.